# Verifying my proposed proof: If $(G:H)=m$, the order of every element of $G/H$ is a divisor of $m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

I just wanted to confirm that I completed this proof correctly, as I have not yet encountered any exercise requiring me to "put down on paper" the following argument.

In Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra, Chapter 15 Exercise E2 asks the reader to prove the following:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H\triangleleft G$. If $(G:H)=m$, then $\forall a \in G$, $\exists n \in \mathbb Z \backepsilon \operatorname{ord}(Ha)*n=m \in \mathbb Z$

or as stated explicitly in the text:

[image: Exercie]

Consider the cyclic group generated by an arbitrary coset $Ha$ belonging to $G/H$...call it $ \langle Ha \rangle$.

Then, consider any other arbitrary coset belonging to $G/H$...call it $Hx$.

Because $\langle Ha \rangle$ is a subgroup, and $Hx$ is an element of the group $G/H$, the following object is a "coset" of $G/H$:

"$\langle Ha \rangle Hx$"...*this is sort of like a "coset of the group that has cosets as its elements"*

Therefore, with this object established, we can now take advantage of **Lagrange's Theorem**.

Using this theorem, we know that $(G/H\ :\  \langle Ha \rangle ) = \frac{|G/H|}{|\langle Ha \rangle|}$.

From what is given by assumption, we know that $(G:H)=m$, however, $(G:H)$ is precisely describing the number of distinct cosets that are formed by $H$. Therefore, $(G:H)$ is equivalent to the cardinality of $G/H$...i.e. $|G/H|$.

As such, $|G/H| = m$

So we have $(G/H \ : \ \langle Ha \rangle ) = \frac{m}{|\langle Ha \rangle |}$

Noting that $|\langle Ha \rangle |= \operatorname{ord}(Ha)$ , and then rearranging, we have:

$\operatorname{ord}(Ha) * (G/H \ :\ \langle Ha \rangle) = m$

Letting $(G/H \ :\ \langle Ha \rangle) = n$, we arrive at the conclusion that $\operatorname{ord}(Ha) * n = m$

Since $Ha$ was arbitrarily chosen, we have proven this to be true for all elements belonging to $G/H$.

Is this a correct argument? Cheers~

Comment: It looks generally correct, but horribly complicated. Don’t you know that if $[G:H]=n$, then $|G/H|=n$? And hence, as a corollary to Lagrange’s Theorem, that every element of the group $G/H$ has order dividing the order of the group $G/H$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin isn't that, in essence, exactly what I just proved (I guess I just did it more explicitly)?

Comment: @S. Cramer: that is the essence indeed, however what you did is not ''explicit'' (which would be a thing of virtue) but unnecessarily convoluted and unpleasant (which pertains to the opposite of virtue)...

Comment: @S.Cramer: What you did seems correct; but your argument is needlessly self-complicated. "Explicit" does not mean adding more lines or going off on unnecessary tangents; nor does it mean in-lining results you have already proven. You can just *invoke* a consequence of Lagrange explicitly, you don't have to *reprove* the consequence of Lagrange's Theorem.